# Animate Drawable icon in Android - ClassCastException VectorDrawable cannot be cast to Animatable

Tags: java, android, xml, vector, android-animation

I'm new to vectors in Android and I want to do a simple icon animation on my app.
I'm actually using Android 9 and Android Studio 3.4.2.
It's my first time asking something here, so sorry in advance if there are some mistakes.

I have followed some tutorials on internet and I managed to create a Drawable image but when I try to animate it my app crashes.

I have added this in my **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is my **/drawable/tick.xml**:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" >

    <group android:name="group"
        android:rotation=".0"
        android:pivotX="12.0"
        android:pivotY="12.0" >

        <path android:name="tick"
            android:pathData="M4.83,12 m-1.42,1.41 L9,19 21,7"
            android:strokeColor="#000"
            android:strokeWidth="2"
            android:strokeLineCap="round"
            android:strokeLineJoin="round" />

    </group>

</vector>
```

Here is my **/animator/my_animator.xml**:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="45.0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Here is the ImageView in the **/layout/activity_main.xml** where I want to see the animation:

```
...
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_demo"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tick" />
...
```

And in my **MainActivity.java** I have this:

```
...
        final ImageView tickImage = findViewById(R.id.image_demo);

        tickImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Animatable animatable = (Animatable) tickImage.getDrawable();
                if (animatable.isRunning()) {
                    animatable.stop();
                }
                animatable.start();
            }
        });
...
```

When I click on my ImageView I get the exception:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.Animatable
        at com.example.testanimation.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6615)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:784)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26047)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6854)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

on the line where I try to do the casting and the whole app crashes.

I tried to google this problem but I couldn't find a working solution for this problem.
How can I fix this? Is there something I'm missing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out the problem by myself, I'm posting it if someone will need it someday:

In the **/layout/activity_main.xml** I needed to change this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_demo"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tick" />
```

to this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_demo"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/avd" />
```

So I just figured out I needed to set the **animated_vector_drawable.xml** in the ImageView instead of the *"root" drawable image*.